# Add the values of a panda dataframe column if the value of another column is the same

Tags: python

I am still novice in python and I am hitting a wall, I cannot figure out how to add together the values in two lists depending on the value in another list. here is an example to illustrate my thought:

```
 list 1 = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4]
 list 2 = [4,7,6,5,4,7,7,3,5,6]
```

what i would like to do is get this:
For every unique value in list 1 I want to sum up the values in list 2 at same position.

```
dic3 = {1:17, 2:9, 3:14, 4:11}
```

is it possible to do this with list only or do I need a dataFrame?

I have trying doing:

```
  for i in list1:
      if i== i-1:
           count1 =+ i
      else: 
          count1 = 1
```

but it is super off and I do not seem to find a solution, even when I try to put the problem in a numpy array. Would somebody have a hint that could help the situation?

Thank you for your help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear what is the connection between `list 1` and `list 2` to `dic3` (which is not even written as a dictionary, as you may have wanted). Also, the headline of the question has nothing to do with the body of your question.

Comment: Oh sorry for being unclear, dic3 is the result i am trying to achieve. I'll modify my post rn to make sure it is correct

Comment: That is clear, but what in `list 1` and `list 2` causes for example "1:17"?

Comment: so if  list1 and list2 are two columns next to each other, then the three 1 are next to 4, 7, 6 and the calculation that i am trying to make is for all the 1, add the values in list2 that are next to 1, and so on for each value in list1. Does it make more sense?

Comment: in that example, 4, 7 and 6 would be all associated with a 1 in list so adding them up is 17

Answer (score 0):

The answer in your question is wrong, it should be `3:17`

```
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
list2 = [4, 7, 6, 5, 4, 7, 7, 3, 5, 6]
prev = list1[0]
dict =  {}
sum = 0
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if prev == list1[i]:
        sum += list2[i]
    else:
        prev = list1[i]
        sum = 0
        sum+=list2[i]
    dict[prev] = sum
print(dict)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i appreciate your answer, no way I could have come to it on my own. however, the target answer was correct, i guess a good way to put it would be to think of list 1 as the indexes. for each index that is the same, i want to add the corresponding values in the row. in the dataset that i am working on, list1 is a column with SKU numbers, the same number is repeated many times but each time that is repeating, the order quantity in the next column is different and i want to find out how many order quantity is in total for each SKU. Thank you for your help regardless

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` arrays to achieve your result.

```
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
list2 = [4, 7, 6, 5, 4, 7, 7, 3, 5, 6]

unique=set(list1)
arr1=np.array(list1)
arr2= np.array(list2)

dict={}
for val in unique:
    list2 = np.nonzero(arr1==val)
    dict[val]=arr2[list2[0]].sum()

print(dict)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you N.Moudgil, that does the trick, would you recommend using Numpy array every time I am encoutering this kind of problem?

Comment: Numpy, short for Numerical Python. So if you are dealing with lists of numbers and performing high/complex computations, it provides quick and easy to do algorithms.